# How to split command over multiple lines in Nuget Manager Console (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've already tried using back ticks (`) and (^) without success.

Answer (score 2):

A little late for an answer but this worked from me in VS 2019 package manager console. SHIFT + Ctrl + ENTER.
Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's still not supported.
There's an open issue with a [feature request](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8010) on Nuget's official GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shift+Ctrl+Enter, which now works just fine when you type the command manually it also works to copy-paste a command that was split into several lines ealier.

However, it seems to depend when the line break happens. From my experience it is accepted in the middle of the string or a list. Therefore you can copy&paste this:

```
MyCommand -Connection 'Data Source=myDB'-force -Text 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type'
```

or:

```
MyCommand -Connection 'Data Source=myDB'-force -Tables @(
'Table1', 'Table2', 'Table3',
'Table4', 'Table5', 'Table6',
'Table7', 'Table8', 'Table9')
```

but trying to divide it e.g. in between of the parameters ends up with a separate call for each line, first one running with limited params, and the other ones obviously failing

```
MyCommand -Connection 'Data Source=myDB'-force  
-Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -verbose 
-Tables @('Table1', 'Table2', 'Table3')
```